I want to add a shelf bracket to a sagging wooden shelf. What types of screws and wall anchors should I use?
Image: https://ibb.co/n0Bgz6D
I've been told to use wood screws but I'm confused if the wood screws go into the wall or should those be drywall screws. Also what anchor and what size of stew should I use? 8 or 10?
The wall is a dry wall.
Thanks for any help

The answer depends what the rear of the shelf material is.  If that's wood, or if you can find studs, you can use wood screws.  If you can't find studs, you probably need drywall anchors.  When you say "bracket" what do you mean?  IMO you could simply screw another straight piece along the back, just like the sides have.

It's drywall and I was able to find a stud. By bracket, I mean an L shaped metal thing that you use to attach floating shelves for example.

Also, how would I screw a straight wood piece into the wall? Like what screws so I need to use? Anchors or just to the stud? Or both?

Ideally, a stud.  Wall anchors if you must.  You could even use angle brackets to fasten the back support to the sides.

Thanks - what type of wood is the best for a shelf cleat?

There should be wood studs behind the drywall.
You always want to screw into wood studs if any weight is involved. Drywall should only be used to hold up paint/posters.
Find studs, find a decent shelve bracket and use 2 inch screws that fit the holes. #10 is usually a decent average size.

What drill bit size would you use for number 10 wood screw? I'm assuming it should be a wood screw right? Thanks

@Novice_guy222   I have drill bit kits, so I usually eyeball the size.  It should be close(smaller) than the solid shank(without threads).  Quite sure google will tell the exact bit size for a #10 screw.  Pilots holes usually not needed for wood studs.

@Novice_guy222   Take that top shelf and flip it over and restock it. When it levels off, install your new shelf bracket inline so the shelf remaines level.

@Novice_guy222 I use rough estimate, the drill should be 1/2 to 1/4 smaller than the screw, pending on how hard is the material you drill in.

I found the stud and have the bracket. So, just so I'm clear, I use wood screws to attach the bracket to the wall where the stud is and then a drywall screw to attach the bracket into the MDF shelf from underneath?

I have had the same problem and fixed it in several ways, depending on the particulars.  Key points:
1. Easiest first:  Flip the shelf upside down so the curve rises in the center.  The load (stuff you put on it) will tend to flatten it out.  That may be all you need to do, and it will get flatter over time.  You're finished and can ignore the rest!
2. If you don't like the center hump, you can force the shelf straighter: screw a stiff strip of wood (say 1x2) to either the top or bottom near the front or back edge.  Or any combination of these four possibilities, or even on the bottom halfway back.  Do this with it flipped, so gravity works with instead of against you.
3. Your shelf looks like MDF or particle board, which doesn't hold screws very well.  You will be better off putting the screws through it and into the wood strip than vice versa.  Buy a few drywall screws a half inch shorter than the 'shelf + wood strip', and screw through the shelf into the strip.
4. Why drywall and not wood screws?  Both are intended to anchor into wood, but drywall screws work better for most household projects.  They go into wood easily and are less likely than wood screws to split it without the extra step of drilling a pilot hole.  (The pilot hole should be a little smaller than its screw, and preferably drilled with a tapered bit shaped like the screw itself.  Wood screws are generally wider and tapered - narrow at the point and wider near the head; drywall screws are not.)
5. Ideally, you would drill and countersink clearance holes in the shelf.  But you may not need to if it's MDF: the screws may strip out the fibers and/or compress them. You can encourage the process by driving the screws through the MDF until they spin (before you screw them into the wood strip).  [Countersink: When you don't want the head of a screw to stick up above the surface (e.g., so your towels won't snag when you slide them off the shelf), you usually need to drill out the top of the hole with a larger bit. That lets you drive the screw head all the way into the surface where it no longer sticks up and catches things.  A clearance hole is made larger than the screw threads so the screw passes through, allowing it to clamp the top piece to the bottom.]
6. Instead of attaching the strip to the shelf, you can screw it to the back closet wall in line with the two side strips.  That will prevent the back edge from sagging, which may be all you need for linens (but probably not your antique cannonball collection).  Use drywall screws an inch or two longer than the wood is thick.  You don't have to pre-drill or countersink, but you do need to go into studs.

What does countersink mean? I have heard that term but not sure of the specifics.

Countersink:  When you don't want the head of a screw to stick up above the surface (e.g., so your towels won't snag when you slide them off the shelf), you usually need to drill out the top of the hole with a larger bit.  That lets you drive the screw head all the way into the surface where it no longer sticks up and catches things.

Gotcha. Do you mean I should screw through the shelf from the "top" through the shelf into the new wood bar that I purchase? And that's better than a bracket attached to the wall?

Novice_guy222 You've got it.  I prefer strip to bracket for a few admittedly minor reasons: you have to install bracket on a stud, which may be off center, not so elegant. If you're not careful with the stud finder, you may miss the stud or hit close to the edge and split the stud.  You need to screw the warped shelf down to flatten it; doing it with the hump up means your screws go into up into MDF which doesn't hold them well; hump down means screwing down into existing wood strips, hard to do right next to wall.  If you do screw into MDF, use the special screws made for it.

One last question - is screwing a wood strip to the MDF shelf "better" than adding the wood strip to the wall as an additional shelf cleat? By better I mean, easier and/or more effective at bracing the MDF shelf that's sagging. Thanks

Additional cleat more effective because stiffer, but more work:  locate studs,  drill clearance holes in wood, and screw the shelf to the wood before you install it, if you want the shelf to start out flat.  (You have to screw it to something to keep it flat until it loses the curve.)  if you’re just storing light weight stuff, any if these should work fine.

Frame Challenge
Quite literally. Instead of installing a shelf bracket under the shelf, install another piece of lumber to make more of a frame under the shelf.
Measure the side supports. Probably something like 1" x 2". Get more wood of the same size. Cut to match the width between the existing end supports.
Paint it white to match everything else - one coat, doesn't need to be perfect, just enough so that it doesn't look that different.
Screw the support to the wall under the shelf to any studs you can find. In addition you may want to attach it to the side supports.

https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-not-answering-a-question-and-posting-a-frame-chal

@Traveler I know this is not quite a typical "frame challenge" as a long support isn't inherently so different from putting up a shelf bracket. But it is a "frame" and sometimes (well, often) a pun is too good to resists.

How do I screw it to the studs? Wood screws? How long should the screw be assuming a 1x2?

What type of lumber works best as a shelf cleat?

Whatever Home Depot/Lowes/etc. has on hand. As far as screw size - thickness of board + 1/2" (standard drywall) + ~ 1".

Assuming you can use the studs too screw in.
the drill should be 1/2 to 1/4 smaller than the screw, pending on how hard is the material you drill in
If you can not find the studs, use a stud finder, or simple magnet to find the drywall screws/nails which are usually in the middle of the stud.
If you can not use studs, you need special drywall anchors

I got a stud finder and was able to locate the studs thankfully. One potential issue solved.
